# Should I use methods deprecated in 7.0 if the user's iOS version is below 7.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c

- I am using SDK 7.0
- My deployment target is 4.3
- I'm testing with the 5.0 simulator

I see a method that says **"Method `A` is deprecated in iOS 7.0, instead use `B`"** in Apple's documentation.

I think that I got things mixed up, so just to be clear:

- If I identify the user's iOS version (5.0), **should** I use `A` or `B`? Since it is 5.0, `A` should be available, whereas `B` probably not because it was implemented later, right?
- or does the fact that I used SDK 7.0 imply that I should always use `B`, regardless of the user's iOS version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the older method. Method B won't be available under older versions of iOS. Deprecated methods rarely (never so far?) actually go away. The only example is the `UIDevice uniqueIdentifier` but even that didn't go away, it simply returns garbage now.

Of course you could do something like:

```
if ([someClass resondsToSelector(someNewerMethodSelector)]) {
    // call the new method
} else {
    // call the old method
}
```

Code like that will run the newer method if it exists or the old method if not. Similar checks can be made for newer classes too.

BTW - why spend the effort to support iOS 4.3 or even 5.x? Support iOS 7 and maybe iOS 6.x if you have a good reason. Unless you have a specific need or requirement, supporting 4.3 and 5.x is not worth your effort.

And if you do keep support for 4.3, you better test your app thoroughly on a device with 4.3 to be sure you don't accidentally call and 5.0+ APIs.

Comment: The replacement B may be available in the oldest OS version that you plan to run on. The documentation for B should say when it was introduced.

Comment: @GregParker Good point. This is possible. But in this case, the compiler will give a warning of using a deprecated method so it will be clear that a newer method should be used. The compiler warns about any method being used that was deprecated at or before the current Deployment Target.

Comment: When you get a warning "Method A is deprecated, instead use B" then neither "use the older method" nor "use the newer method" is always the correct answer.

Comment: You will only get such a warning if the method was deprecated at or before the deployment target. The replacement method should have been added before or at the deployment target as well. This means that using B would be valid in such a case.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes a method will be added in an OS version and both the old and the new are supported, then the old method will be deprecated in a yet-newer OS release.

Lately Apple has been releasing an updated method/class/API and deprecating the old one at the same time.

That means that if you are supporting old OS versions, you have no choice. You HAVE to use the old way of doing things in the old OS because the new way doesn't exist. So if you support iOS 5, 6, and 7, you can only use the new method if you write runtime code that checks to see if it is supported. Then you need to decide what to do about the old OS versions.

Sometimes it's simpler to just use the deprecated method and be done with it. That code works for all supported OS versions.  However, that's less "future-proof" than writing code that checks at runtime and only uses the deprecated method if the newer version isn't available.

Imagine you have an app that runs on iOS 5, 6, and 7. You use a method that changed in iOS 6. It was deprecated in iOS 7, but still works. If you just use the deprecated method, it works in all 3 target OS versions, but what about iOS 8 when it comes out? When Apple deprecates a method/API/class it means that at some future date they are going to remove it completely.

Doing a runtime check and using the deprecated method if the new version isn't available is the most work, but the most future-proof. In iOS 8, if Apple removes the deprecated method, your code works. In iOS 5, the new method isn't available, so your code uses the old method. It is a pain in the butt however.

Comment: There are APIs that were deprecated in iOS 3.0 that actually still exist and still work. I'm not aware of any API that actually was removed sometime after being deprecated. Do you know of any? Just curious.

Comment: @maddy, sure. The method shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation was deprecated in iOS 6, and was dropped in that same OS version. If you want to handle user interface rotation in iOS <6.0 and >=6.0, you have to implement both that method and the new supportedInterfaceOrientations method.

Comment: Granted, methods do tend to stick around for a long time after they are deprecated, but there are exceptions, and Apple seems to be moving faster recently.